How do I disable OPTIONS Method in IIS?
This is Windows 10 computer.
The IIS manager is not installed.
The web.config file does not exist.
How do I disable OPTIONS method?
UPDATE: I do not want to install any additional features. This is a minimal Windows OS configuration, with many features disabled for security reasons.

I assume that you should have admin access and should be able to run a PowerShell script . Can you try this scrip snippet and assuming you want to do it for the "Default Web Site" , if there is a specific site that you want , then please replace the site name with the appropriate SiteName information.
# Import the WebAdministration module
Import-Module WebAdministration

# Get the IIS site you want to modify (replace with your site name)
$siteName = "Default Web Site"
$site = Get-Website -Name $siteName

# Check if the Request Filtering module is installed
if (-not (Get-WindowsFeature Web-Filtering).Installed) {
    Install-WindowsFeature Web-Filtering -IncludeManagementTools
}

# Disable OPTIONS verb for the site
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -Location "$site/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/verbs" -Filter "add[@verb='OPTIONS']" -Name "allowed" -Value "false"


The second line of your script produces error: "Import-Module : The specified module 'WebAdministration' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory."

Also, I do not want to install any additional features. This is a minimal Windows OS configuration, with many features disabled for security reasons.

It is actually part of the IISAdministration module itself ( Install-Module -Name IISAdministration ) , while i understand the hardening part but this module does not add IIS Manager , rather the libraries .
